# Is this a good game to play with my children?

Tags: play-time, play, fighting, life-skills, imaginative-play

I have a game with my children that I wear a necktie, trousers and boxing gloves to look formal and we do a friendly, gentle boxing match. My 3 children are 10 years old and they love this game. I fight them very gently and I let them hit me, when I get hit 5 times I am knocked out - dad is defeated - I fall to the floor I lie on my back with my eyes closed and sometimes with my tongue outside, and the "fight" continues, it makes my children laugh and they celebrate "dad's(mine) knock out" by standing on my belly or jump on me or they pull my tie, if my "child partner" wins and I lie on floor "unconscious" - he lifts my tie up like he won with me. I am very delighted that they like this game and it makes them happy,

on the next rounds, I "win" very gently and my "match partner" is happy that I helped him. I lift my hands up and I smile, My "defeated" child lying on his side with eyes closed and nothing happens, and my kids argue which side I will choose, everything is done very gently and sometimes roughly and the kids are happy, is this a creative nice game?

Comment: It sounds like a lot of fun for everyone, so that's truly lovely. You should also play non-combative games, too, though, that are also fun if you can. I'm voting to close this as opinion-based (as you can see from the answer below, the opinions are going to be all over the place.) Keep on being a great dad!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a lovely game. Your kids are learning how to celebrate wins without making the losing kid feel bad for losing, while also learning how to lose without explosive emotions.

Children are often powerless in the world so playing games where they can feel powerful (even if they know it's pretend) helps them learn how to manage that feeling.

I also love games that include [heavy work](https://lovevery.com/community/blog/child-development/heavy-work-an-expert-strategy-to-calm-your-active-toddler/#:%7E:text=Heavy%20work%20is%20any%20activity,%2C%20bouncing%2C%20or%20even%20chewing.). It's great for sensory regulation for people of all ages!

Answer (score -4):

I mean I dont think you should let your kids win.Sadly everything in life is earned ,the outside world doesnt show you mercy so there isnt room for parent-pampering.

Comment: But I also beat them.

Comment: You should beat them EVERY time if you can.Its called tough love.

Comment: I absolutely disagree. The outside world won't show them mercy, as you said, which is why I wholeheartedly believe it's why parents, the child's supposedly safest and most comforting person, absolutely should. Otherwise, the kids will never learn how to show mercy and they will perpetuate a merciless world which we all know isn't great.

Comment: This answer shows a very severe lack of understanding... No matter what game you play with your kids they need to win 30% of the time... At least.

Comment: The fact that the outside world doesn't show mercy (disputable), doesn't mean we have to be part of the problem.